# import huge option list into main component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React 16.12, and I have a component that contains a select dropdown box for a form.  The option field section is huge...like over 75 choices.  With it being so long, I don't want to clutter up my main form component.

So I tried putting it in a separate file called options.js like this:

```
<option selected>Open this select menu</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
```

But whenever I try to import, I just get this error:

```
  Failed to compile
  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment 
  <>...</>?
```

I want it do look something like this in the main form component:

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./options" As OptionListing;

const App = () => (

   <Form>
      <select name="optionTypes">
          <OptionListing>
      </select>
   </Form>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but you need one encapsulating component, try this.

```
import React from "react";

const OptionList = () => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default OptionList
```

This is an alternate way of doing the same thing in shorthand (newer React versions)

```
import React from "react";

    const OptionList = () => {

        return (
            <>
                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </>
        )
    }

    export default OptionList
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Would this require a 'return' statement or anything?  Because I'm getting this error: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression "

Comment: sorry, yes, this itself should be its own component.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try modifying `Options.js` like below

```
<React.Fragment>
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</React.Fragment>
```

OR return array of elements like

```
const options = [
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>,
  <option value="1">One</option>,
  <option value="2">Two</option>,
  <option value="3">Three</option>,
];
```

and use as

```
<Form>
  <select name="optionTypes">
      {options}
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reusable Select component like this:

```js
export default function Select({ name, options, handleSelected }) {
  return (
    <select name={name} onChange={e => handleSelected(e.target.value)}>
      {options.map(({ key, title }) => (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {title}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "./Select";

const options = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: "Option 1"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: "Option 2"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    title: "Option 3"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const onSelected = option => {
    console.log(option);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <Select
          name="optionTypes"
          options={options}
          handleSelected={onSelected}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also put the options to a file, and import it to the App.js.

For example:
options.json

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "title": "Option 1"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "title": "Option 2"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "title": "Option 3"
  }
]
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "./Select";
import options from './options.json';

export default function App() {
  const onSelected = option => {
    console.log(option);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <Select
          name="optionTypes"
          options={options}
          handleSelected={onSelected}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-montalcini-kmxkh)

If your options fields keys are different from key and title, before passing the options, you may use Array.map() to transform.

Comment: this looks promising but it still kind of has the same problem of the key/title data being in the app.js file.  I was trying to move it out of there because it's so long (over 75 options).

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell you can put the options as json in a different file, and import it into the App easily. Please check the updated codesandbox

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I also updated answer, how to put the options to a json file, and importing it to the App.js. Now App.js is very clean.